# asp.net web page scraping with https://livingsocial.com

Tags: asp.net

page scraping with https://livingsocial.com

currently i am working with following code.

this code sends request for user authencation ,but web page does not validate user.

```
        string appURL = "https://livingsocial.com/deals/external_people/login";

        string strPostData = String.Format("login={0}&password={1}","bilalqadeer122000@gmail.com", "03006403836");

        // Setup the http request.
        HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(appURL) as
        HttpWebRequest;
        //old code
        wrWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wrWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)";
        wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        wrWebRequest.ContentLength = strPostData.Length;
        wrWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        wrWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

        // Post to the login form.
        StreamWriter swRequestWriter = new
        StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        swRequestWriter.Write(strPostData);
        swRequestWriter.Close();

        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();

        // Read the response
        StreamReader srResponseReader = new
        StreamReader(hwrWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string strResponseData = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

The cookie container has to be used with next webrequest. Only then you'd get the effect of being logged in.

Comment: how can i use cookie container for next request tell me with coding.

Answer (score 1):

You have already done the hard part by creating a seperate variable for your container.

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
wrWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

Just as [Hasan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454900/asp-net-web-page-scrapping-with-https-livingsocial-com/7454935#7454935) indicates you merely need to keep passing it along with each request.

```
var newRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/");
newRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

var yetAnotherRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.anothersite.com/");
yetAnotherRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

This will preserve the cookies, and more than likely your session, across each subsequent request.

Comment: i get the cookies and save like that. foreach (Cookie c in hwrWebResponse.Cookies)
            {
                myContainer.Add(c);
            }
and use in new request like that but no response was there.
HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest1 = WebRequest.Create(appURL) as HttpWebRequest;
            wrWebRequest1.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            wrWebRequest1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)";
         wrWebRequest1.CookieContainer = myContainer;

Comment: @Wasif, there is no need to iterate through the cookies and add them to your container. If you inspect your container between calls you will notice that all the cookies are there. You simply need to continue to pass the container along with each request.